# redis-rb multi only increment if key set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, race-condition

I want to store a count in redis. I want to increment the count only if the key exists. What am I doing wrong? exists is returning false and the incr is being executed.

```
key = "blah"
result = REDIS_DB.multi do
  exists = REDIS_DB.exists(key)
  REDIS_DB.incr(key) if exists
end

# result: [false, 1]
```

I am new to redis. I just read [the redis transactions doc](http://redis.io/topics/transactions). From what I understand, the commands in multi should execute one after the other?

Rails 4.0.2, Redis 3.0.1, [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) (A Ruby client library for Redis)

Answer (score 3):

As of redis 2.6 lua scripting is supported and it is [transactional by definition](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#redis-scripting-and-transactions) so following code can be used as well.

```
redis_script = <<SCRIPT
    local exists = redis.call('exists', KEYS[1])
    if exists == 1 then
        return redis.call('incr', KEYS[1])
    end
SCRIPT

# returns incremented value if key exists otherwise nil
REDIS_DB.eval(redis_script, ['testkey'])
```

Read more about [scripting and eval command](https://redis.io/commands/eval)

---

Coming to why `incr` in your actual code executed was because

Each `REDIS_DB` function call in `multi` block will return a `Redis::Future` object not an actual value, as `redis-rb` caches the commands in multi block. e.g.

```
REDIS_DB.multi do 
    return_value = REDIS_DB.exists('tesstt')
    puts return_value.inspect
end
```

will print

```
<Redis::Future [:exists, "tesstt"]>
```

Now, If we got through the block in your example

```
exists = REDIS_DB.exists(key) # returns Redis::Future object
REDIS_DB.incr(key) if exists  # evaluates to true as value of exists is an object
```

So where does `result: [false, 1]` comes from.

This is because `REDIS_DB.multi` after yielding your block (and caching the commands) finally converts it into redis query and sends it to redis which eventually runs it and returns the result. so your code is actually converted into following query.

```
MULTI
exists 'blah'
incr 'blah'
EXEC
```

and submitted together in a single call to redis which returns `0` for `exists` ( which `redis-rb` converts into boolean `false`) and 1 for `incr`.

Point to be noted is that this behavior is understandable as if you send each command individually to redis then redis itself will queue everything after `MULTI` and process it when call to `exec` is received

Comment: This comment is a *LIFESAVER!* The OP's scenario was relatively small, but this  particular Redis `multi` gotcha was causing an INSANE headache in my case. I had a `if ... else if ... else ...` block, and literally ALL the commands in that block were executing, and FOR THE LIFE OF ME, I couldn't figure out why. The ONLY explanation was that the `if, else-if` and `else` conditions were not being evaluated, and I COULD NOT figure out why the language, itself, was breaking like this!

Answer (score 1):

This might be what I was looking for:

```
result = REDIS_DB.watch(key) do
  if REDIS_DB.exists(key)
    REDIS_DB.incr(key)
  else
    REDIS_DB.unwatch
  end
end
```